# How do I find the derivative of y^n=x?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

impartial differentiation. I have already logged both side and gotten to n*ln(y)=ln(x) then differentiated, but then it just turns into a mess and the last place I got to was y(1-x*ln(y))/(xn)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is what V 13.3.1 gives me  `eq=y[x]^n==x; D[eq,x]`   ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82zB6.png)  It looks correct to me. Is this not what you expect?

Comment: *impartial differentiation* This is called *implicit* differentiation.

Comment: You want the derivative with respect to what?

Comment: Thank you, thats the right one, and the question wants the derivative of y respect to x

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqn1 = y^n == x;

eqn2 = ApplySides[Dt[#, Constants -> n] &, eqn1]

(* n y^(-1 + n) Dt[y, Constants -> {n}] == Dt[x, Constants -> {n}] *)

eqn3 = Assuming[n y^(n - 1) Dt[x, Constants -> {n}] != 0,
  DivideSides[eqn2, n y^(n - 1) Dt[x, Constants -> {n}]]]

(* Dt[y, Constants -> {n}]/Dt[x, Constants -> {n}] == y^(1 - n)/n *)
```

Or more directly, using [`ImplicitD`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitD.html)

```
ImplicitD[eqn1, y, x]

(* y^(1 - n)/n *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do implicit differentiation from scratch. Assume you have an equation in implicit form:

```
f[x,y]==0
```

Now the differential of f is zero:

```
df[x,y] = D[f[x,y],x] dx + D[f[x,y],y] dy ==0
```

And from this:

```
dy/dx== -D[f[x,y],x] / D[f[x,y],y]
```

For your function:

```
f[x_,y_]= y^n -x

dy/dx = -D[f[x, y], x]/D[f[x, y], y] = y^(1 - n)/n
```